# how many ways can all 10 different prizes be given to the 6 consolation winners so that 1 gets 3 prizes, 2 get 2 prizes each, and 3 get 1 prize each?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I don't know if my answer is correct.

10P3 = 720 for the one person,

7P4 = 840 for the two person,

3P1 = 3 for the three person

720+840+3 = 1563 ways

Assume all 6 people are distinct as are all 10 prizes and we don't care what order they received the prizes, only which ones they get.

Comment: Are the winners distinct?

Comment: Clarify what you mean by ways are all the prizes distinct and are consolation winners distinct?

Comment: The winners. You said the prizes are distinct ...but what about the winners?

Comment: The winners are also distinct

Comment: @NiñaLizaDicdican Oh!  OK, I just answered when the winners are not distinct ... let me add the case where the winners are distinct.

Comment: Why are you adding?  Shouldn't you multiply?

Answer (score 2):

Your calculation is not correct in various respects ...

Assuming the winners are distinct:

Pick $3$ prizes for $1$ winner: You can pick $6$ different winners, and you can pick $3$ gifts in ${10 \choose 3} =120$ ways.  You need to divide your $720$ by $3$ since, for example: picking gifts 1,4, and 7, is the same as picking gifts 4,7,and 1.

Now we need to pick two winners of $2$ prizes. We can pick those winner in ${5 \choose 2} = 10$ ways. Once we have done that, we can pick $2$ gifts from the remaining $7$ for the 'older' of the two in ${7 \choose 2} = 21$ ways, and then we can pick $2$ gifts from the remaining $5$ gifts for the 'younger' of the two in ${5 \choose 2} = 10$ ways.

Finally, the last $3$ prizes can only be divided in $3!=6$ ways between the last $3$ winners, rather than in just $3$ ways, which is what you said.

And, to get the grand total of possibilities, your *big* mistake is that you need to *multiply* those possibilities (since for *each* of the ways to pick the first group of $3$, there are the many ways to pick the next group of $2$, etc.). So, rather than add them, you should get:

$$6 \cdot {10 \choose 3} \cdot 10 \cdot {7 \choose 2} \cdot {5 \choose 2} \cdot 3! = 9072000$$

Comment: Be careful.  The order in which you distribute the prizes to the two people who receive two prizes each does not matter.  You should choose which two people receive two prizes each, then select two prizes for the younger recipient and two prizes for the older recipient.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Argh!  And I had that at first too ... This constantly messes me up ... Thanks!

Comment: Your explanation makes sense, but I am getting $9072000$ using the same numbers as you.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig I see I had a typo (I had 94432000) ... but I am getting 54432000, which is 6 times your number ... recalculating .... no, still getting 54432000 ... ugh....

Comment: Do you have $6 \cdot 120 \cdot 10 \cdot 21 \cdot 10 \cdot 6$?

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Ha! No ... I kept using the 720 from the OP instead of the 120 :P  OK, thanks!!

Comment: This remains very incorrect.

Comment: You are permuting $3$, twice, why?

Comment: @amWhy The first $6$ is to choose the 1 person out of 6 winners. The last $3!$ is where I permute the $3$. So I only permute it once ... or am I missing something?

Comment: The last 3 do not all have the same number of prizes to pick from. See my answer.